# RDD[(Long, Node)] How to access and update?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So im trying to create something like this:

```
val initVertices  = initGraph.vertices
val vertices  : RDD[(Long, Node)] = initVertices.map{v =>
  val vId  = v._1.toLong
  val vData  = new Node(vId)
  vData.id = vId
  Tuple2(vId , vData)
}
```

Im trying to access for Node.weight for every element in 'vertices' and trying to update the value, can someone help me how? great thanks..

*ps: im new on scala and spark

Comment: what is Node? and vertices? Could you provide some more context about your problem. Maybe some library used for that?

Comment: @BorisAzanov so i created class named Node and inside that class there are some attributes (like id, weight,etc)  and vertices are the rdd variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to create case class Node, look at method copy of Node case class, it can create another Node from existence but with some new values:

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

case class Node(id: Long, weight: Long)

val initGraph: Graph[Long, Any] = ???
val initVertices: VertexRDD[Long] = initGraph.vertices
val vertices: RDD[(Long, Node)] = initVertices.map{
  case (vertexId: VertexId, value: Long) =>
    val vId = vertexId
    val vData = Node(vId, value)
    (vId , vData)
}
val nodeA = Node(1L, 1L)
val nodeB = nodeA.copy(id = 2L)
```